# jQuery - select only one child tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select the tag `a` only which inside `my-div`.

```
<div id="my-div">
    <li><a class="class1" href="href">text1</a>
        <ul class="ul-internal">
            <li><a href="....">....</a></li>
            <li><a href="....">....</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</div>
```

What I'm doing now is `$("div#my-div li a")` and it returns all tags inside first li.
Your suggestions?

Comment: Do you want only the first li a tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$('#my-div >li a');`

If you want to select only the first `a` tag then you would want to use

```
$('#my-div > li a:first');
```

**[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hMZmd/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can select by index. Supose, you want to select the first `a` by:

```
$("div#my-div li a").eq(0)
```

For the second `a`,

```
$("div#my-div li a").eq(1)
```

and so on...

Comment: Please don't use `:eq()`. that selector cannot leverage `querySelectorAll()` and is therein slower than `.eq()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:-

```
div#my-div li a:first
```

### Example:

```
$("div#my-div li a:first").each(function() {
    alert($(this)​.attr("href"));
});
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/GYRqh/)**

Answer (score 0):

There should be ID selector which is `#`

```
 $("#my-div li a")
```

By the way your HTML structure is not valid.